# replace parenthesis opening and closing tags with () tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a string or integer formula which will look a code between parentheses.My logic is this: Search for the first parentheses, find the last parentheses, and return everything in between. Im sure there is a string or integer function, but not exactly sure which one will do the trick. And by the way, the code in between the parentheses varies from length 3 to 9.kindly check this code enter code here

```
var n;
var $;
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var p = str.indexOf(")");
var q = str.indexOf("(");
var res = str.replace(")", "");
var re = str.replace("(", "");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
var k = str.replace("$", "(" + "$")
           .replace(/,$/, ".")
           .replace(")", "(" + res + ")")
           .replace("(", "(" + res + ")")
           .replace(/O/g, 0)
           .replace(/o/g, 0)
           .replace(/g/g, 9)
           .replace(/\s/g, "");
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = k;
```

Comment: Have you considered [lastIndexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) ?

Something like `var p = str.indexOf("("); var q = str.lastIndexOf(")"); str = str.substr(p + 1, q - (p + 1));` (untested, may be off-by-one errors).

Comment: Is there any specific problem with the code you have? If not, for code reviews please refer to  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be about code review.

Comment: Did you ever figure out my answer? It works just as you asked. I would appreciate the accept on it.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can understand of your question, you just want to search a string of anything and pull out the characters that are surrounded by paranthesis. This is very easy.

```
var foo = 'blah(capture this)blah';

var result = foo.match(/\(([^()]+)\)/);
//this simply says: capture any characters surrounded by paranthesis, as long as there is at least one character.

console.log(result[1]);
```

#### Update based on your comments:

The logic is very easy to follow.

```
var regex = new RegExp(
  '\\(?'+ //optional (
  '\\$?'+ //optional $
  '(\\d+)' //capture any digit, at least one
);

function format(userInput) {
  var results = userInput.match(regex);
  if (results === null) { results = [0,0]; }
  //get the important part (the digits), format it however you want.
  var formatted = '($'+results[1]+'.00)';
  return formatted;
}

//all output ($1234.00)
console.log(format('$1234)'));
console.log(format('($1234.00'));
console.log(format('1234'));
console.log(format('1234.0'));
console.log(format('1234)'));
console.log(format('(1234.0'));
```

Comment: And this will actually not work if you want `blah"capture "all" of this" blah` to capture `capture "all" of this`, will it?

Comment: @Tibos fixed, my mistake :) I'm tired.

Comment: @CompuChip good point, It was meant to be paranthesis (as I just changed), but still relevant. Let me work on that.

Comment: i also want to replace some thing for which i have written code there like g to 9,o to 0 for which i have done successfully but my question is  that if i write  1234) then it should come (1234) or i write (1234 then it should come (1234) can anyone guide me how to do this??

Comment: @Punit You probably are going to need to learn regex for yourself to get exactly what you want...I'm not so sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: i have a textbox where user can put by mistake $1234),($1234.00 But the result should be ($1234.00).

Comment: @Punit see my updated answer. It does exactly what you asked and the user can mess up just about anything http://jsbin.com/oWUmeDaQ/1/edit still works. Click the accept arrow on my answer if that helps.

Comment: not exactly means syntax are not true like javascript is not accepting console.log  anyway thanks u tried thank u so much @m59

Comment: @Punit what? My code works perfectly. Your previous comment about `console.log` doesn't make sense. Further, the console isn't relevant to the code...it's the `format()` function that matters. I was just logging the result. Does this makes more sense to you? `document.body.textContent = format('(1234.0');`

Comment: is there anybody who can answer for this question?? urgent

Comment: @Punit lol...I answered it, perfectly. I don't know what you're not getting.